# Remove commas and decimal places from number field

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to add two zero place holders in front of a field without changing the actual values involved. The field is an order number that is being pulled from MOMs. So right now that fields' formula is `{cms.ORDERNO}`.

When I try `'00'+{cms.ORDERNO}` the field displays `001,254.00`. How can I remove the decimals and comma so it displays `001254`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual trick is to pad with plenty of extra digits on the left and then only take the six you really want from the right. This would handle any order number ranging from 1 to 999999.

```
right("000000" + totext({cms.ORDERNO}, "0"), 6)
```

When you don't specify a format string, as you tried, it uses default settings which usually come from Windows. By the way, if I recall correctly `cstr()` and `totext()` are equivalent for the most part but `totext()` has more options.

You should also be able to specify "000000" as the format string to produce the left-padded zeroes. Sadly I don't have Crystal Reports installed or I'd check it out for you to be sure. If this is the case then you probably don't need a formula if you just want to use the formatting options for the field on the canvas. If you do use a formula it's still simple.

```
totext({cms.ORDERNO}, "000000")
```

Comment: the to text worked perfect.. and it makes so much sense! Thank you for all your help!!!! you are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use the Replace formula a few times for this. The formula below converts ORDERNO into string, removes any commas and trailing decimal places, then adds the two zeroes at the beginning:

```
`00` + REPLACE(REPLACE(CSTR({cms.ORDERNO}),".00",""),",","")
```

So for example, if `cms.ORDERNO` is `1,254.00` the output from this formula would be `001254`

Comment: I think this would work.. however the order number is normally 001254, but when I try to add the zero's it includes the zeros and then additionally adds the decimals and commas. I tried using the formula you gave me but it says it wasn't a formula, I'm guessing that's because there are no decimals or anything in the actual order field BEFORE I edit it. Any idea with this additional inf?

Comment: If the decimal/comma appear after adding the zero, you could always flip the order of operations. Try `REPLACE(REPLACE(CSTR('00' + {cms.ORDERNO}),".00",""),",","")` instead

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older, but better solutions exists and I ran across this same issue. ToText has what you need built right in.

**"00" + ToText({cms.ORDERNO}, 0, "")**

From the Crystal Documentation:

> ToText (x, y, z)
>
> x is a Number or Currency value to be converted into a text string; it
>   can be a whole or fractional value.
>
> y is a whole number indicating the number of decimal places to carry
>   the value in x to (This argument is optional.).
>
> z is a single character text string indicating the character to be
>   used to separate thousands in x. Default is the character specified in
>   your International or Regional settings control panel. (This argument
>   is optional.)